# integral of a k-form over an oriented compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, stokes-theorem

I see in my course the following theorem:

If $\omega$ is an exact k-form over an oriented compact manifold M of dimension $k$, then $\int_M  \omega=0$.

I don't have a proof of this theorem and I only know it's an application of stokes theorem.

Is this theorem correct?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: stokes theorem...

Comment: Why don't you just use that $\omega$ is exact and then apply stokes theorem on you  own?

Comment: Because it's not as easy as it seems. Apply stokes theorem on wich manifold(boundary, interior)? is the integral 0 because there is no boundary, or is it because $\omega$ is closed then $d\omega=0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \text{With }\omega = d\eta, \qquad \int_M \omega = \int_M d\eta = \int_{\partial M} \eta = 0 \quad \text{since }M \text{ has no boundary.}$$